# Limit towards infinity

Tags: limits

If $f(x)$ goes toward zero as x increases towards plus or minus infinity, can I then say that for each epsilon exists a $k$ so $|x| > K$ implies that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$?

I know that if we take only the plus infinity limit, then there's a M so all x bigger than M make f(x) less than epsilon, but I am not sure what happens when x goes toward negative infinity, and how we can "join" those informations together.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two definitions:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = 0 &\iff \forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists K\mbox{ s.t. } x > K \implies |f(x)| < \varepsilon\\
\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = 0 &\iff \forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists K\mbox{ s.t. } x < -K \implies |f(x)| < \varepsilon.
\end{align}$$
As you can see only the part regarding $x$ and $K$ changes. If you want to say that $f$ goes to $0$ both towards negative infinity *and* towards positive infinity, you can write
$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x) = 0 \iff \forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists K\mbox{ s.t. } |x| > K \implies |f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$

However, note that if you only know that one of the two is true, you cannot conclude anything about the other limit towards the other infinity. The function could not even exist there!